# get Firebase nodes by children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a database that is set up like so

```
-users
  -uId0
    -Name: "Bill"
  -uId1
    -Name: "Bob"
  -uId2
    -Name: "Dave"
```

How do I get the uId elements if there name child starts with B. 
The query should return somthing like this?

```
  -uId0
    -Name: "Bill"
  -uId1
    -Name: "Bob"
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DatabaseReference myReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
    myReference.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {          
              //looping all your users
              for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
              {
                  name = (String)messageSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();

                  if (name.toLowerCase().contains("b")) {            
                          //u can save your name with 'b' string here
                  }
              }                   
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
     });
```

Comment: uhg that is kind of a painful way to do it I was hopping someone new a better way than to fetch the hole of the users node. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uId = (String) ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference uIdRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uId);
            uIdRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
                    if (name.matches("^[B].*$")) {
                        System.out.println(name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```